# np.logical_or() in Numpy - Python

Tags: python, numpy

Please anyone can explain me this resulting code

```
x = np.array([9, 5])
y = np.array([16, 12])

np.logical_or(x < 5, y > 15)
```

Result -> `array([ True, False])`

Since:

1. `np.logical_or(x < 5, y > 15)`
2. `x < 5 = [False, False], y > 15 = [True, False]`

I think it should be:

```
[False or False, False or True] = [False, True]
```

In fact Python giving the result like this:

```
[False or True, False or False] = [True, False]
```

Why the result is not [False, True], but in fact python giving the result [True, False]?
It is not match with the order of operation `np.logical_or(x < 5, y > 15)`

Even I tried ChatGPT explanation I still don't have clear understanding of this concept.

Please I would be appreciate, if anyone can explain the background of python process in detail step by step.

---

Comment: "Even I tried ChatGPT explanation" - ChatGPT is a bullshit generator. It generates output that superficially resembles something that makes sense. Don't bother trying to ask it to explain things for you.

Comment: Have a look at the numpy `ufunc` basics: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.ufuncs.html#ufuncs-basics and the documentation: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html. `np.logical_or`, similar to `np.add` or `np.multiply`, for instance, will do the computation element-wise between the two inputs, not within each input separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are interpreting the result wrong. Numpy's `logical_or` can have a few arguments as filters. In your case, the input arguments are `x < 5` and `y > 15`. It then combines them together with an `or` operator.

- The first argument `x < 5` would lead to: `[False, False]`
- The second argument `y > 15` would lead to: `[True, False]`
- The final result = `[False or True, False or False] = [True, False]`